# how to subtract first value from the last one within a column across a row in shell?

Tags: shell, sed, awk, perl

I have a data file looks like :

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 
2 4 5 8 9 10 13 17 19 29 30 32 33 50 700 800 900 950
```

first I want to insert space among each 3 identical values keeping each three identical numbers together in one colum  by looking at the first row :

```
1 1 1  1 1 1  1 1  2 2 2  2  3 3 3  3 3 3 
2 4 5  8 9 10  13 17  19 29 30  32  33 50 700  800 900 950
```

and then I want to  subtract the first value from the last one within each new column at second row ( but if there was only one value at a specific column(here the forth column at second row), then the last value from the previous column should be subtracted from that value(32-30)) while keeping one unique number out of each column from the first row. so the final data should be like this:

```
1 1 1 2 2 3 3
3 2 4 11 2 667 150
```

any suggestion please? meanwhile I should mention my real data is indeed huge and I want to group each 5 unique values at first row. I may want to change the size of group . So I need the script to be flexible ..

Comment: Tried anything ?

Comment: I read your requirements about 10 times before I understood them.  (Perl is definitely the tool for this, by the way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $group_size = 3;

my @first = split ' ', <>;

my @groups;
my $start_index = 0;
while ($start_index < @first) {
    my $step = 1;
    while ( $step < $group_size
            && $start_index + $step < @first
            && $first[$start_index] == $first[ $start_index + $step ]
          ) {
        ++$step;
    }
    push @groups, $step;
    print $first[$start_index], ' ';
    $start_index += $step;
}
print "\n";

my @numbers = split ' ', <>;

my $last;
for my $size (@groups) {
    my @group = splice @numbers, 0, $size;
    my $value = $group[-1] - $group[0];
    $value = $group[0] - $last if 1 == $size;
    $last = $group[-1];
    print $value, ' ';
}
print "\n";
```

You haven't specified what should happen if the very first group has just one member.

Comment: choroba that wonts happen.

Comment: @zara: Just specify the data file name as the parameter of the program.

Comment: @zara: T.I.T.S. = Try It To See.

Comment: should I do like this to make it run?   ../yourscript.pl  data.txt

Comment: @zara: If you first make the script executable by `chmod u+x program.pl`, then yes

Comment: @zara: To redirect output to a file, just add `> output`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35036/discussion-between-zara-and-choroba).

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to choroba's answer

```
$ cat file
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 
2 4 5 8 9 10 13 17 19 29 30 32 33 50 700 800 900 950 

$ perl -ane '
    if ($. == 1) {
        for (($n,$i,$j) = (1,0,0); $j < @F; $n++, $j++) {
            if ($n == 3 || $F[$j] != $F[$j+1]) {
                $i-- if $i == $j;
                push @pairs, [$i, $j];
                $n = 0;
                $i = $j + 1;
            }
        }
        printf "%d ", $F[ $_->[1] ] for @pairs;
    }
    else {
        printf "%d ", $F[ $_->[1] ] - $F[ $_->[0] ] for @pairs;
    }
    print "\n";
' < file
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 
3 2 4 11 2 667 150
```

For the first line of input `($. == 1)` it calculates the list of pairs of indices you are interested in. This works out to:

```
[[0, 2], [3, 5], [6, 7], [8, 10], [10, 11], [12, 14], [15, 17]]
```

Comment: does your script works in case if I want to change the group size from 3 into 20?

Comment: meanwhile my real data is huge and I need to specify input file in a seperate file than script . how it is possible by your script?

Comment: first comment: change `$n == 3` to `$n == 20`. second comment: I don't understand what you're saying -- possibly you want to change `< file` to `< the_real_name_of_your_input_file`

Comment: i mean how should i run this? should i do like:  perl  yourscript.pl input.txt  > out.txt ?

Comment: I do not know how to run I copied exactly what you wrote in script in to a .plfile and i tried to run.. but wont work :(

Comment: You run it like `perl -ane 'all the stuff in single quotes including newlines' input.txt > out.txt` -- if this is a concern for you, I'd recommend going with choroba's answer

Comment: ok let me try first

Comment: yey! it works . but in output I get 4 rows, which the firt two are the answer and the last rows are zeros:

Comment: (1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5)
(3 2 4 11 2 667 150 120 10 20)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)

Comment: OK, you have blank lines in your input file. Add this line before `if ($. == 1)`  => `next unless @F;`