# How to group a bunch of rows based on information from the first row?

Tags: shell, sed, awk, perl

I have a data file looks like :

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3  . . .
1 0 4 4 3 1 2 0 0 0 3 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 3  . . .
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 1 1 2 3 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 2  . . .          
.
.
.
```

first I want to insert space among each 5 identical values keeping each 5 identical numbers together in one colum by looking at the first row and then I do not want anz space among those group characters:
 first step:

```
1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  1  2 2 2 2 2  2 2 2  3 3 3 3 3  . . .
1 0 4 4 3  1 2 0 0 0  3  1 1 2 1 1  1 1 1  1 0 1 1 3  . . .
0 0 0 0 0  0 0 3 3 1  1  2 3 2 1 2  2 3 1  2 3 1 2 2  . . .          
.
.
.
```

secouns step (output):

```
11111  11111  1  22222  222  33333  . . .
10443  12000  3  11211  111  10113  . . .
00000  00331  1  23212  231  23122  . . .          
.
.
.
```

Meanwhile in my real data which is huge I may want to try different group sizes. So I need the script to be flexible ..
any suggestion please?

Comment: Use `sed(1)`, or a scripting language like Perl or Python.

Comment: Can you not use the code given to you from your [last question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258534/4667)?

Comment: @glennjackman I tried but it did not work.

Comment: You should show us what you tried so we can help you improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other variant with **awk**

```
awk '
    NR==1{
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
            count++
            if($(i-1)!=$i || count>4){
                D[i]=1
                count=0
            }
        }
     }
     {
        for(i in D)
            $i=" "$i
            print
     }
     ' OFS="" data.file >new.file
```

And **sed**

```
sed -re '
    s/ +//g;s/^/\n/
    ' -f <(
        sed -r '
            s/(. )\1*/s_\\n(&)_\n/g
            s/\S /./g
            s/\n\s*/\\1 \\n_\n/g
            s/\\n[^\n]*\n$/ \\n__/
            1q
        ' data.file
        ) -e '
    s/\S{5}/& /g
    ' data.file >new.file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an awk script. You just change the number `5` to have other groupings.

```
awk '
NR==1{
 previous = $1
 for(i = 1;i<=NF+1;i++)
  if($i!=previous){
    col[++numcol] = i
    previous = $i
  }
}
{ j = 1; start = 1
  for(i = 1;i<NF;i++){
   printf "%s",$i
   if(i==col[j]-1){printf "  "; start = col[j++]}
   else if((i-start+1)%5==0)printf "  "
  }
  printf "%s\n",$NF
}'
```

The first part just handles line 1, and collects in array `col` the starting column for each set of same numbers.  The second part prints each field with no separation, unless on column 5 from the starting column, or at the end of a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do it would be to use perl's [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Packing-Text) function, with a template constructed from the first line of the file.

After removing whitespace, it uses a regular expression with a repeating backreference to find the longest contiguous strings of identical characters not exceeding the given `maxwidth`, and stores their positions in an array. The fieldwidths are extracted by subtracting adjacent elements of the array, and mapped into a suitable template string of the form `A5A5A1A5A3A5A3` to pass to the `unpack` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift or die "Usage: $0 FILENAME MAXWIDTH\n";
my $maxwidth = shift or die "Usage: $0 FILENAME MAXWIDTH\n";
open my $infile, $filename or die "Could not open $filename: $!";

my $n = $maxwidth-1;
my $template;

while( my $line = <$infile> )  { 
    $line =~ s/\s+//g;

    if ($. == 1) {
        my @ends = (0);
        while ($line =~ /(.)\g1{0,$n}/g) {
            push(@ends, pos $line);
        }
        my @fieldwidths = map $ends[$_] - $ends[$_-1], 1 .. $#ends;
        # http://stackoverflow.com/a/29821158/4440445
        $template =  join "", map { 'A' . $_ } @fieldwidths;
        # http://stackoverflow.com/a/2725663/4440445
    }

    my @fields = unpack($template, $line);
    print join " ", @fields;
}

close $infile;
```